# PHP: Allocating Memory with php.ini or init_set

Tags: php, web-services, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I keep getting the following message when running a script:

```
Out of memory (allocated 58458112) (tried to allocate 20 bytes)
```

When I change the memory_limit in the php.ini or put `ini_set("memory_limit","1024M")` at the top of the script, the message is the exact same, as though no additional memory was used to run the script. Is there something else I can do to allocate more memory (outside of optimizing the script... it's Magento, which needs an overhaul, but it don't have the expertise to fix it).

Comment: is this PHP script ran on a shared hosting server? BTW: 58MB is quite a lot for a PHP script.... I doubt it's only Magento that needs this

Comment: Are you sure that the command is working? Try using `ini_set` on a test page, and then output `phpinfo`. Make sure the memory limit actually has changed.

Comment: The script is being run on a VPS. I made the set page and it's changing the value... it's weird to me that the numbers don't change on the error message no matter what limit I put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to your ulimit settings. Run `ulimit -a` and you will probably find something around that 58MB mark, i'm guessing 64000. You can change it with the `ulimit` command, but will probably need to edit /etc/security/limits.conf to make it persist.

Comment: It says "max locked memory": 32, "max memory size": 200000, "virtual memory": 200000. Unfortunately I don't see anything around 64000.

Comment: I'd try changing the 200000 numbers to 500000 and running it again. It's possible that script is forking or something and the parent php process ends up hitting the 200M limit even though your final script dies at 58M.

Comment: Noob question, but how do I change the value? I'm connected via ssh

Comment: Heh no worries. Add these lines to the limits.conf file:

Answer (score 0):

Magento is a real memory hog, we've had to upgrade the server to run it.

Try setting the memory limit in the top level .htaccess file to something like this (which is working for us)

php_value memory_limit 256M

(If you're on a shared server this may have no effect either but it's worth a try.)